# Golang Gin framework importing HTML templates from sub sub directory

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm using `Go` version `1.8.1` with `Gin` framework and my project structure like below

```
|- src/
    |- views/
        |- category1/
              |- layout/
                  - header.html
                  - footer.html
              - index.html
        |- category2/
              |- layout/
                  - header.html
                  - footer.html
              - index.html
        |- category3/
              |- layout/
                  - header.html
                  - footer.html
              - index.html
```

In each of the `index.html` I have to include the same level header and footer files from `layout` folder, to do that for `category1` folder `index.html` I wrote like below

```
{{ template "views/category1/layout/header.html" .}}
<body>
    <h1>Category 1</h1>
</body>
{{ template "views/category1/layout/footer.html" .}}
```

and in `Gin` I loaded all files using

```
router.LoadHTMLGlob("views/*/*/*.html")
```

but it is not working as I expected, it is giving the following error:

> html/template:index.html no such template "views/category1/layout/header.html"
> html/template:index.html no such template "views/category1/layout/footer.html"

Comment: Harish, did you define your templates as such? Does the file at `views/category1/layout/header.html` have a template definition with the correct name, like this: `{{define "views/category1/layout/header.html"}} .... {{end}}`?

Comment: thank you @mkopriva, router.LoadHTMLGlob("views/*/*/*.html") is correct syntax, because now it is showing `html/template: "index.html" is undefined`